# Tippy.js z-index not working with interactivity

Tags: css, tippyjs

Ref: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

The z-index seems not be working when specifying `interactive:true` (then it falls behind other elements) although I specify the `#main_container`. How can I get it "on front of everything" with `interactive:true`?

```
delegate( '#main_container', {
target: '[data-tippy-content]', allowHTML: true, 
interactive: true, placement: 'right', theme: 'light', zIndex: 99999
} );
```

see also here: https://github.com/projectje/bookmark for the above code. I made a temporary workaround by placing a BR behind every first character so that it will not flow over other boxes. But this is really a short-term workaround.

Comment: Did you specify `z-index` as `zIndex` (with capital I)? See docs (at bottom): https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v5/all-props/

Comment: i changed it to zIndex but it does not seem to make a difference

Answer (score 6):

The tippy is appended to the reference element's parent by default when `interactive` — this can cause it to be clipped if the parent is a "containing block".

To fix use one of these:

- Use `popperOptions: { strategy: 'fixed' }`, or
- Specify `appendTo: document.body` + focus management for keyboard usage

Comment: what do you mean by "+ focus management for keyboard usage"?